# Can you cast an address to an object instance in vb.net?

Tags: c++, vb.net, interop

I'm exploring various ways to do c++, vb.net fused projects. What I love about c++ is that you can load up a bunch of binary data, give it a pointer with the appropriate type and bam! You have yourself a pod object instance.

I'm looking a way to do the same in vb.net but I'm rather fuzzy on the way vb.net handles its memory. Basically, is there a way to convert binary data into an object without too much overhead in a manner that the exact same data would also be viable in c++ and its equivalent class definition? Further more, could you do that to binary data in another processes memory or perhaps shared memory without moving the actual data? (so that if both c++ and vb.net programs object instances point to the same chunk of memory, if one changes the data, the other one is instantly up to date too)

Comment: VB.NET does not have support for pointers, look at the C# or C++/CLI languages.  Marshal.PtrToStructure() provides a way to marshal binary data, sharp edges that draw blood are included.

Comment: You are entering a world of pain trying to do something like this in VB.NET.  The language just wasn't designed for it.  You will have much better luck using a language that was designed to work with pointers (C#, for example).